# Error saving .pdf files into MySQL as BLOBs using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf

I did a small form in HTML that allows you to add files and records everything in a database.

Everything works correctly when I save images, but when I try to save the PDF file type doesn't work.

Does anyone could tell me where I am failing?

Thank you all.

---

Code of Form

```
<tr><td>File:</td><td>

 <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf" maxlength="200" title="Choose File" >

 </td></tr>
```

---

PHP code to save in database

```
$image=  addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
            $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

        if($image_size==FALSE)
            echo "";
        else{

    $insert = "INSERT INTO table(name, date, image)

            VALUES ('$name', curdate(), '$image')";

    mysql_query($insert);
        }
```

Comment: Whats the error? Remember that you tell your browser to accept 200 Bytes only (`maxlength="200"`)

Comment: thansk for reply. Dont save anything in the database. The file Itried to add in pdf is small.

Comment: You should use [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) function to know the error. Also, [**please don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

`getimagesize()` returns FALSE for non image files (eg pdf). Your insert was never executed.